# Use multiple ThenBy directly without any order

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to sort based on multiple columns simultaneously in LINQ.

To achieve to this sorted list I should use `SortBy` for the first column and then multiple `ThenBy` to sort the result of `OrderBy` by another column.

But the problem is that I don’t have any order in using `ThenBy`(s) and that's because user chooses the first column and I use this column as parameter to `OrderBy` and the rest of columns are parameters to `ThenBy`.

So I first, declare a dynamic global variable like :

```
dynamic result;
```

Then create an entity model like :

```
DatabaseEntityContext context = new DatabaseEntityContext();
```

And query data to get an adequate Anonymous Data Type :

```
    var query1 = db.context.Select(x => new { Column1 = x.Column1, Column2 = x.Column2,
 Column3 = x.Column3, Column4 = x.Column4, Column5 = x.Column5 }).ToList();

    var query2 = query1.Select(x => new { Column1 = x.Column1, Column2 = x.Column2,
 Column3 = x.Column3, TotalColumn = x.Column4 + "-" + x.Column5 }).ToList();
```

And finally assign `query2` to `result` like :

```
result = query2;
```

To use LINQ functions on `result` I cast it to `((IEnumerable<dynamic>)result)` 
but the thing is the result of this cast doesn't have any `ThenBy` extension and I can't use `OrderBy` first because the list may already been sorted by another column and I should use a `ThenBy` to sort it again based on the result of previously sorted list.

My problem is, I have multi factors to use in `ThenBy` but I can’t sort this because I should `OrderBy` first,then use `ThenBy` after `OrderBy` and I can’t use `ThenBy` directly.

So how can I use `ThenBy` directly with a previously ordered list ?!

**Update 1 :**
According to @Patrick Hofman I changed my cast type to `IOrderedQueryable` like :

```
result = ((IOrderedQueryable<dynamic>)result).ThenBy(x => x.MyDynamicField).ToList();
```

but no it gives me a compile error on `"x.MyDynamicField"` :

> An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

I also test `IOrderedEnumerable` but it gives `InvalidCastException` error :

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`5[System.String,System.String,System.DateTime,System.TimeSpan,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]]'
>   to type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[System.Object]'.

Comment: Sounds like you need to determine if your `result` is `IEnumerable` or `IOrderedEnumerable`.  But it's hard to tell.  If you mean ordering was done before the `ToList` then I hate to tell you, but you'll have to do that ordering again before adding addition `ThenBy` calls.

Answer (score 4):

`ThenBy` is an extension method on `IOrderedQueryable`, not `IEnumerable`. If you want to call `ThenBy`, you should cast it to an `IOrderedQueryable`:

```
var r = ((IOrderedQueryable<dynamic>)result).ThenBy(...);
```

As juharr commented, you can even expand this to check the type and then chose either `ThenBy` or `OrderBy`, using the same predicate to filter on.

Comment: @PatrickHoffman It gives me error. I updated question according to your solution.

Comment: You still have reflection to get the property value.

Comment: How ? It gives me "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation" error !

Comment: Then use `object` instead and use reflection.

Comment: I don't think so. I change the code to : `((IOrderedQueryable<object>)result)` and now it gives me : 'object' does not contain a definition for 'MyDynamicField' and no extension method 'MyDynamicField' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: So you didn't use reflection to get the property.

Comment: Im sorry for my silly questions ! If I correctly understand you I changed my code to this : `result = ((IOrderedEnumerable<object>)result).ThenBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("Date")).ToList();
`  but It now gives me this error :  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`5[System.String,System.String,System.DateTime,System.TimeSpan,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]]' to type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[System.Object]'.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` you could:

```
public static class QueryableOrderBy
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBySimple<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
    {
        var ordered = source as IOrderedQueryable<TSource>;

        if (source != null)
        {
            return ordered.ThenBy(keySelector);
        }

        return source.OrderBy(keySelector);
    }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByDescendingSimple<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
    {
        var ordered = source as IOrderedQueryable<TSource>;

        if (source != null)
        {
            return ordered.ThenByDescending(keySelector);
        }

        return source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
    }
}
```

These methods will "analyze" if there is already another `OrderBy` (then they will use `ThenBy`) or not.

Comment: I have error in using IOrderedQueryable in code because in this case it doesn't recognize my dynamic variable.
I updated my question accoding to use of IOrderedQueryable.